# SQL - select distinct

Tags: sql, vb.net, select, combobox

I used the select disctinct statement with 2 fields from my sql database table. Here is my code.

```
myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Author FROM tblBook UNION SELECT DISTINCT BookCode FROM tblBook",myConnection)
 myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
 myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tblBook")
 cboAuthor.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
 cboAuthor.DisplayMember = "Author"
 cboAuthor.DisplayValue = "BookCode"
```

and it generates error : `cannot bind to the new member. Parameter name:value`. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have selected only one column in your sql statement, Author.
BookCode isn't present so it won't be in the dataset either.

Include the BookCode in the Sql Statement and it will be fixed

Comment: Isn't it in the Union?  I can't run unions in my head so I don't know how his SQL will return lol

Comment: just include the bookcode in the sql and it'll be fine "SELECT DISTINCT Author, Bookcode FROM tblBook"

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you are looking for

```
SELECT DISTINCT Author, Bookcode FROM tblBook
```

Union is used to merge rows not columns..

So your query returns a single column where you have all the autors (distinct) followed in the same column by rows of all the bookcodes (distinct as well).

Answer (score 4):

A UNION operation does not work in this way.

You want a recordset containing two columns - Authors and BookCodes so you are going to need a query something like:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Author, BookCode FROM tblBook
```

Answer (score 1):

You make a query of two distinct things.

You either want to...

1. Get the author of each book. In that case have to make a query joining the tables, so union is not an option
2. You indeed need the result as one column, in that case give the column an alias and bind the alias

   SELECT DISTINCT Author AS mycolumn FROM tblBook 
   UNION 
   SELECT DISTINCT BookCode AS mycolumn FROM tblBook