# vb.net - select distinct not get the result wanted

Tags: vb.net, select, combobox

I used the following code to select unique values from the database

```
myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT DISCTINCT Visitor, BookCode FROM tblBook", myConnection)
 myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
 myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tblBook")
 cboAuthor.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
 cboAuthor.DisplayMember = "Author"
 cboAuthor.ValueMember = "BookCode"
```

And it does not retrieve the unique values, it remains the same. But if I use only `SELECT DISTINCT Author FROM` tblBook it works fine.

Please help.

Comment: Why ask another question for a similar code that you have posted in your [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571485/sql-select-distinct)? You may edit your earlier question to update your finding and improve the question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT` will ensure that no duplicate records are returned in the result set.

Therefore if you only put SELECT DISTINCT Author, you will get a list of unique authors.

Putting `SELECT DISTINCT Author, Visitor, BookCode` may return duplicate authors, with different visitor or bookcode.

Comment: but actually, i want only the unique author even their bookcodes are different, any idea?

Comment: This isn't logical though, as what would appear in the BookCodes field if the values are different? You either need to remove this, or use an aggregate function to decide which one to display

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT DISTINCT** would get all distinct values of **ALL** fields.

Answer (score 0):

everything is right. select DISTINCT returns all unique combinations of all fields that are in SELECT clause.